# Как создать файл с правами 777 в nodejs?

Tags: node.js

как правильно создать файл с правами 777 в nodejs?

Я пробую сделать так:

`fs.createWriteStream(filename, {mode: 0o777})`

Но получаю права на файле - `755`

Как я понял из [статьи](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) - `0o777` это максимальное значение

Comment: Изменить umask? https://x-team.com/blog/file-system-permissions-umask-node-js/

Comment: @andreymal Пробовал `var mode = 0777 & ~process.umask();` но фаил все равно создавался с правами 755, сейчас решил проблему изменяя права после создания файла `fs.chmod()`

Comment: Блин, почему нет нормальных статей про umask в nodejs? Ну ладно, прочитайте википедию тогда https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask